# Dagger 2. Library and app has different version

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have library with class provided via @Inject constructor. Library compiled used old dagger version (2.11). I want use (inject) this class in app module, which use new dagger version (2.14.1). In this case, dagger classes are generated with an error.
Is it possible to use different minor versions of the dagger?

Message error:

```
Error:(25, 51) error: incompatible types: ClassA cannot be converted to Provider<ClassA>
```

Error generated code:

```
 @Override
  public void injectMembers(OtherClass<M> instance) {
    OtherClass_MembersInjector.injectStandardErrorHandler(
        instance, ClassA.get());
  }
```

Comment: You're passing in an instance of ClassA, when it expects a Provider<ClassA>.  Pass in the right type.

Comment: @GabeSechan This is generated code. I have no power here

Comment: Libraries should never depend on dependency injection frameworks. This is a big design mistake on part of library's maintainers. If that's an internal library, ask the maintainers to remove dependency on Dagger completely. Otherwise, I would say, consider removing the library altogether.

Comment: @Vasiliy agree. We solved problem in this way

Comment: @Vasiliy  Hello I am developing android SDK and have watched your course... I also need dependency injection in the library. Should I use Dagger, or build my own DI? Or maybe use another solution? What would You suggest? :)